# Error: To view the information on this page, ask a global or SharePoint admin in your organization to go to the API management page

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx, graph-api

I am following a SPFX tutorial to setup my first Graph call. When I run the call, it suppose to see an API request pending for my approval.

I tested my webpart at localhost bench, click the button to trigger Graph call and got console error "Error: To view the information on this page, ask a global or SharePoint admin in your organization to go to the API management page in the new SharePoint admin center."

That's it. In the SharePoint admin site "API access" page I see no pending task. How could I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I tested my webpart at localhost bench. If I test with https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx, the API access request will be submitted properly.

Comment: In my case its coming at https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx,